# How to make it so each enemy is given a random time difference?

Tags: python, random

My game variables

```
#Game rules
time = 1
time_passed = 0
complete_time = 400
enemy_timer = random.choice([1000,2000,3000])
finished_enemy = pygame.time.get_ticks()
enemies_alive = 0
```

My creation of enemies

```
#creating enemies 
    if time_passed < complete_time :
        if pygame.time.get_ticks() - finished_enemy > enemy_timer:
            r = random.randint(0, len(enemy_types) - 1)
            enemy = Enemy(enemy_health[r],enemy_animations[r], WINDOW_WIDTH - -10, WINDOW_HEIGHT - 260, 2) #gets arguments from enemy class and where they are(location)
            enemy_1 = Enemy(enemy_health[r],enemy_animations[r], WINDOW_WIDTH - -10, WINDOW_HEIGHT - 160, 1)
            enemy_2 = Enemy(enemy_health[r],enemy_animations[r], WINDOW_WIDTH - -10, WINDOW_HEIGHT - 60, 3)
            enemy_group.add(enemy,enemy_1,enemy_2)
            finished_enemy = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            #allows for increasing difficulty
            time_passed += enemy_health[r]
            print(time_passed)
```

Sorry for wording of the question as i dont know how to describe what i want in a sentence.

Anyway I have the code for randomizing three values for enemy_timer (1000,2000,3000) what it does is separate the images of my enemy by millisecond. I want it to affect enemy, enemy_1 and enemy_2 differently. Such as when i run enemy has 1000 enemy_2 has 3000 so on.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do but `enemy_timer` has always the same value. You should run `random.choice([1000,2000,3000])` for every enemy separately. And keep this value inside `Enemy`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the random function once, you should use it separately for each enemy.

For example in this object

```
enemy = Enemy(enemy_health[r],enemy_animations[r], WINDOW_WIDTH - -10, WINDOW_HEIGHT - 260, 2) #gets arguments from enemy class and where they are(location)
```

You should use

```
enemy = Enemy(enemy_health[random.randint(0, len(enemy_types) - 1)],enemy_animations[r], WINDOW_WIDTH - -10, WINDOW_HEIGHT - 260, 2) #gets arguments from enemy class and where they are(location)
```

for your each enemy object